# VB.NET application unable to run on other computer

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I can debug my project with no errors, but when I build it and copy the executable application to another computer, the application is not running at all. The form does not even appear on screen.

([Here](http://postimg.org/image/h3tmdiwwz)) is the screenshot of my error.

Here is my source code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim MySQLConnection = New MySqlConnection
    Dim Command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim MyAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim str_carSql As String


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim response As Boolean = False
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Try
            response = My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.db4free.net")
            Label2.Text = "ONLINE"
            Label2.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Button1.Enabled = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label2.Text = "OFFLINE"
            Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            MsgBox("No internet connection!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Try
            MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = "server=db4free.net ;port=3306; user=prav5ef; password=prav5eF; database=databasetest;"
            MySQLConnection.Open()
            MsgBox("Connected to server!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failed connecting to server!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
        Try
            str_carSql = "insert into databasetest (id,name,password) values (@id,@name,@password)"
            sqlCommand.Connection = MySQLConnection
            sqlCommand.CommandText = str_carSql
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox1.Text)
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text)
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox3.Text)
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ID existed: Could not insert record")
        End Try
        MsgBox("Done")
        Application.Restart()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is how the application suppose to show :

[image]

And the online database that I am using is db4free.net :
[image]

Comment: Did the error actually state "bla bla"?  Or was there *more information* about the error that you're just ignoring?  The application could be failing with a *specific* exception, and that would include helpful information about the problem.  Is there anything in the Event Viewer?  Perhaps you can add more error handling to the application itself, such as a global error handler which logs to a file or something like that?

Comment: The error message is short. Not really an error message i think. More like a message when your application lags and stop running. I have not tried event viewer. Everything works fine on the development pc though

Comment: Is `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` present in the GAC or did you reference a dll for that namespace? If you are referencing a dll in your project directory, you may need to copy that dll as well. Else, make sure that assembly is present in the GAC of the target PC.

Comment: Really you are not helping us to help you. What is the exact error message please?

Comment: Does the window load at all? If not the error could be in the declarations at the top of your code i.e. `Dim MySQLConnection = New MySqlConnection`, which happens when the form is constructed.

Comment: @Steve It wasn't really an error i think. Here's the screenshot of the window that pop out after awhile.
http://postimg.org/image/h3tmdiwwz/

Comment: @DanVerdolino Here is the screenshot. The window does not load at all but load up perfectly on my own pc, not my friends's.
http://postimg.org/image/h3tmdiwwz/

I got a feeling that your steps might be right. So what do I need to do with that line?

Comment: NET Framework missing or MySql.Data.Dll missing. This is usually the symptom of a missing component required by your app and not available on the target PC. Of course a NET application requires the NET libraries installed on the target machine (NET Framework) and every other library included in the References of your project Looking at your code, apart from the NET Framework, an obvious reference is the MySql NET/Provider. You should distribute MySql.Data.dll in the same folder of your app.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for the explanation. Just to make it clear, a computer that does not have net framework installed wont be able to load the app right? Is there any easier way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide enough information on the error, these are the following problems you might be experiencing, and the solutions to said problems:

A.) Your client may not be running the correct .NET framework for your Program. In which case, install the correct .NET Framework by downloading it [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/net/downloads)

B.) You did not include the mysl.data.dll on the client unit. In which case, download the .dll from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html) and install it in the client unit.

Comment: Here is the screenshot. Sorry for the late reply.
http://postimg.org/image/h3tmdiwwz/

Info - I have not tested your steps yet

Comment: Steve's comments were right. Download the correct .NET installer. Check my edits on my answer. I added a link there.

Also, don't forget to upvote or mark the correct answer of people who helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. Cant upvote you guys though. Not enough reputations. Sorry